# Where can I find a fast (1KHz) LCD plate?

Tags: lcd, camera

I'm *not* looking for a graphic or text LCD display here, just essentially a single, large pixel, capable of going from dark-light-dark in under 1ms. The faster, the better.

The idea is to create a secondary shutter for a still camera, increasing the [flash sync speed](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/syncspeed.htm#why) of the camera. Here's a video of a similar idea, but on a CMOS video camera. Seems like they're using a pane from a pair of 3d shutter glasses, which operate at video speeds (60 or 120 hz, not fast enough.)

Something like the panel in an auto-darkening welding helmet would be along the lines of what I need, providing they can also transition from dark-light at high speeds.

What are these called? What can I search for (LCD panel obviously doesn't help)? Where might I be able to find one? (Aside from hacking apart a welding helmet.)

Comment: Those auto-darkening welding goggles claim to be able to go dark in 1/25000 seconds. How are they able to switch so quickly?

Comment: Be advised that liquid crystal switching speed can be very slow in low temperatures. A range of faster than the human eye can perceive at room temperature to a second for a black/white change at -15 degC is well possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for sounds like an **LCD shutter**, specifically a **Pi Cell LCD Shutter**. The more modern welding helmets use the **TN LCD Shutters** which have the same slower speeds as 3D shutter glasses. From what I've read the Pi Cell LCD Shutters can have a switching speed of up to 1000Hz.

[Liquid Crystal Technologies](http://www.liquidcrystaltechnologies.com/products/LCDShutters.htm) claim they'll send you a free 1"x1" or 4"x1.5" TN LCD shutter or a 1"x1.5" pi cell shutter. The pi cell shutter will be the faster one. I've never needed an LCD shutter, so I can't verify anything any company claims about theirs, but free is certainly worth a try if you can get them to send you one.

Comment: This looks like it might work. Bonus points for linking a place that might provide a free sample.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve a problem in videography: CMOS rolling shutter effect ("jello effect", wobbly vertical lines when panning), which is due to the sensor being read one line at a time.

Modern cameras with a "global shutter" (where all the sensor is read at once) are **very expensive**. I guess if is just an easy and cheap, all video cameras would be equipped with that now. But I read that LCD shutter cause a great reduction in light transmitted of 50% or more by polarizing light, and it's very hard to make them totally transparent.

Red seem to have used an LCD shutter on one of their (very expensive) digital cinema cameras. I don't know how they do it, and how bad the side effects are.

Anyway if there is an answer I'd be very interested. I mean LCD shutters are found in cheap 3D glasses - I am interested in an LCD shutter with great optical qualities.